# Ways to detect native memory (held by managed objects) leaks in UWP

Tags: memory, uwp

While performing memory profiling using Visual Diagnostics Tools for my UWP app, i came across an instance of "Native memory (held by managed objects) as shown in the picture below from one of the snapshots.

[Image showing the Native instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6ga8.png)

I am not sure how to find out which managed object is influencing the Native memory and a reliable way to solve this. This instance continues to grow and does not reduce.

Any ideas what StackFrameHelper is ? Should this be of any concern ?
Are there any tools which would help in identifying the root cause and solving them ?

Comment: Right now, we're looking at less than "1 megabyte". While that sounds like a lot, it isn't.

Comment: Yes it is. Any ideas what StackFrameHelper is ?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stacktrace.cs,59 It should be used to capture frame info. Could you please share your detailed steps and screenshots to help us reproduce this behavior?